# onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) is not calling

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged

In my application i just overriden the method onConfigurationChanged method as given below

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    System.out.println("Configuration Changed");
    Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();

    if (c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // portrait

    } else if (c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // landscape

    }
}
```

But it is not beeing called when the screen orientation is called.

In manifest my Activity is like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: onConfigurationChanged is in MainActivity ? MainActivity is visible when you change the orientation ?

Comment: did you completely uninstalled since you added this attribute ?

Comment: what have you tried? There are several answers on SO related to your problem. Nothing helps?

Comment: @njzk2 Yea.. Orientaion is changing(going to landscape and portrait) But the Sys out i put in the method is not being called.

Comment: Yes man i uninsatlled and installed again

Comment: @Leonidos nothing helped. it is simple thing i am missing somthing somewhare :-(

Comment: Try this android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not called `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);` so the method became

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

  System.out.println("Configuration Changed");
  Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();

  if (c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    // portrait
  } else if (c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // landscape
  }

}
```

and also added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest.

Thanks SSS :-)